# Can't change the bootstrap port,in appium

Tags: android, appium

I want to use appium server to serve two app,because I first launch my app,and then I launch SMS app to check the login sms message.

It's need two session,so I should launch two separate appium with different ports.

First appium:  -p 4723 **-bp 1000**

Second appium: -p 4800 **-bp 2000**

The "-p" changed correctly,but the bootstrap port didn't change.

First appium's log show here:

```
 >Launching Appium server with command: C:\Program Files\Appium\node.exe lib\server\main.js
 --address 127.0.0.1 --port 4723 --app F:\AppJavaProject\eHomeTest\
 ehome-release-v2.3-123.apk --bootstrap-port 1000 --platform-name Android --platform-version 18 --automation-name Appium --device-name "zteg720t" --log-no-color

> info: [debug] Forwarding system:1000 to device:4724

> info: [debug] executing cmd: F:\AppJava\adt-bundle-windows-x86\
adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s ZTEG720T forward tcp:1000 tcp:4724

> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Socket opened on port 4724
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Appium Socket Server Ready
```

Second:

```
 >Launching Appium server with command: C:\Program Files\Appium\node.exe lib\server\main.js
 --address 127.0.0.1 --port 4723 --bootstrap-port 2000 --platform-name Android --platform-version 18 --automation-name Appium --device-name "zteg720t" --log-no-color

> info: [debug] Forwarding system:2000 to device:4724

> info: [debug] executing cmd: F:\AppJava\adt-bundle-windows-x86\
adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s ZTEG720T forward tcp:1000 tcp:4724

> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Socket opened on port 4724
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Appium Socket Server Ready
```

The first app connect to appium well,then the second app try to connect to appium,it cause the first app's session quit automatically by appium.

I think it's because two session can't use the same bootstrap port 4724.

How to solve the problem?

Please help